# Remove specific jQuery click event from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I understand event can be removed from an element by using .unbind() or .off().
However I am wondering if is that possible to remove specific click event and leave others attached.
For example assuming I have a element with two events attached as follow:

```
$("#MyDiv").click(function() {
alert("I am first Event");
});

$("#MyDiv").click(function () {
    alert("I am second Event");
});
```

Is that possible to remove First event and leave second one attached, using some sort of key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [event name spacing](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$("#MyDiv").on('click.first', function () {
    alert("I am first Event");
});

$("#MyDiv").on('click.second', function () {
    alert("I am second Event");
});

$("#MyDiv").off('click.first');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hhuLcpfg/)